# Change data frame values using a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I'm trying to change the values in multiple different data frames with the same columns:

```
   ColA  ColB  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
1  "A"   "A"      0   0.5   1.1     0
2  "A"   "B"    3.5   3.0   3.1     0
.  ...   ...    ...   ...   ...   ...
```

ColA and ColB are factors, but I don't know if this matters. This is my function:

```
x <- data.frame(ColA <- factor(...), ...)
y <- data.frame(...)

my.fn <- function(df) {
  df$Col5 <<- df$Col1 / df$Col2
  df$Col6 <<- df$Col4 / df$Col3
}

my.fn(x)
my.fn(y)
```

but it gives me the error:

```
Error in df$Col5 <<- df$Col1/df$Col2 :
  object 'df' not found
```

How can I refer to variables inside a data frame `df` using a function?

Comment: The error is actually `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`.

Comment: Try replacing `<<-` with with `<-`.

Comment: `<<-` is normally used for global assignments. R might be looking for `df` in parent environment and not in the function itself.

Comment: closure error normally comes when a variable is undefined and a part/subset of it is accessed/assigned.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using some tools from the Tidyverse. Here's a quick and easy solution to your problem. The pipes `%>%` just feed the output of one function to the next function. So I take `df` and then use the function `mutate` to add a new column named `Col5` to the dataframe. With the mutate function you can call columns without having to use the `$` because we already have specified we're interested in `df` in code above, so it's a bit cleaner. Then I do the same thing for `Col6`. We save it all to `output` using the `<-` at the top.

```
library(tidyverse)

output <- df %>%
  mutate(Col5=Col1/Col2) %>%
  mutate(Col6=Col4/Col3)
```

Comment: Can I use this on multiple functions at once? Maybe a for loop?

Comment: I'd need an example of what you'd like to do, but the beauty of pipes is that you don't need to store to intermediate variables. So it keeps your workflow cleaner and easier to follow. At least in my opinion.

Comment: Sorry, I meant multiple data frames. The only functions I need are `Col5 = Col1 / Col2` and similar, and the pipes accomplish that

Comment: Just BTW you don't have to use piping to use mutate. I just think stylistically it's cleaner. So you could do `output <- mutate(df, Col5=Col1/Col2)`, you can replace `df` with whatever you like. I suppose you could pass a vector of output names and data frame names in through a loop if you'd like to process a large number of data frames in the same manner.